# Try to store Object in iCloud but don't see any action iOS

Tags: ios, icloud

I use [this tutorials](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2011/10/24/sync-preference-data-with-icloud.html) to store object into iCloud (*Key-value Storage*).

My GUI had only one button that triggers: `pressButton` method

Here is a relevant code:

```
NSString *const keyStorageStr = @"keyForStore";

/* ... */

- (IBAction)pressButton:(UIButton *)sender {

    score++;

    [DemoiCloudViewController setScore: score];

    scoreCountLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", score];

    // store to preferences
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setInteger:score forKey:keyStorageStr];

    // store to iCloud 
    [self setInteger:score forKey:keyStorageStr];
}

- (void)setInteger:(int)value forKey:(NSString*)key {
    [self setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:value] forKey:key];
}

- (void)setObject:(id)value forKey:(NSString *)key {

    NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore *store = [NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore];
    if (store) {
        [store setObject:value forKey:key];
        //[store synchronize];
    }    
}
```

And this is my handler:

```
NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore* store = [NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore];
    if (store) {

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(storeChanged:)
                                                     name:NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChangeExternallyNotification
                                                   object:store];

        [store synchronize];
    }

- (void)storeChanged:(NSNotification*)notification {/* .. never called .. */}
```

Here I get proper value: `file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/76Z3CR95HF~com~wifi~icloud~WiFi-iCloud-Demo/`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    ubiq = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
                   URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
    if (ubiq) {
        NSLog(@"iCloud access at %@", ubiq);

        isIcloudActive = true;

    } else {
        NSLog(@"No iCloud access");
    }
```

When I added handler to listen on everything:

```
NSNotificationCenter *notifyCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [notifyCenter addObserverForName:nil
                              object:nil
                               queue:nil
                          usingBlock:^(NSNotification* notification){
                              // Explore notification
                              NSLog(@"Notification found with:"
                                    "\r\n     name:     %@"
                                    "\r\n     object:   %@"
                                    "\r\n     userInfo: %@",
                                    [notification name],
                                    [notification object],
                                    [notification userInfo]);
                          }];
```

I get:

```
name:     _UIApplicationSystemGestureStateChangedNotification

     object:   (null)

     userInfo: (null)
```

From xCode iCloud stats:

[image]

Please help,

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you delete your app and re-run it? Can you retrieve the value from iCloud? Unless there's some other configuration problem that you've not mentioned, my guess is that you can.

The reason: the notification that you're expecting to see only happens when the change comes from iCloud (I.e., originating from another device). The notification *will not* be triggered when you save a value -- why would it be? You already know the value that has been written!

Comment: Yep, you are right, didn't think about uninstall. It works as expected. Thank you